# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'done' of #<Object>

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an application made with Cordova/Ionic. I am using AngularJS. I have the following problem.

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'done' of #<Object>
at fn.assign (eval at <anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:1:0), <anonymous>:4:390)
at $$writeModelToScope (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:38359:5)
at writeToModelIfNeeded (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:38353:14)
at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:38347:9
at validationDone (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:38275:9)
at processAsyncValidators (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:38258:9)
at $$runValidators (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:38202:5)
at $$parseAndValidate (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:38340:10)
at $commitViewValue (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:38308:10)
at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:38441:14 

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'criticality' of #<Object>
at fn.assign (eval at <anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:26457:15), <anonymous>:4:482)
at $$writeModelToScope (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:38359:5)
at writeToModelIfNeeded (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:38353:14)
at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:38347:9
at validationDone (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:38275:9)
at processAsyncValidators (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:38258:9)
at $$runValidators (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:38202:5)
at $$parseAndValidate (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:38340:10)
at $commitViewValue (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:38308:10)
at $$debounceViewValueCommit (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:38438:12)
```

After I have done some research on the subject, I realised that this type of error appears when you use `'USE STRICT'` in your javascript file ([click here for the documentation explaining this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Read-only)). The problem is I never did. I am not using `'USE STRICT'`. Now here's the even weirder thing. The problem is only occuring on a Samsung GT-N5110 tablet with Android 4.4.2. It does not happen on a Samsung Galaxy S7 with the latest update installed. If I use the command `ionic serve` to lunch the appplication on my computer, it doesn't happen either. It works perfectly as intended. It only happens on the Samsung tablet. I tried many things, but I can't find any solution. It is important that it works on the tablet because these are the tablets that we will use for our work.

It happens on multiple variables, but I'll provide the code of the variable 'done' as seen in the first error message.

The view where I click on the `ion-checkbox` to change the value of 'done'

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="item in etapes" ng-click="itemDetails(item.id)">
    <div class="item item-text-wrap">
    <p><b>{{'components.inspection.etape.card.title'  | translate}}</b> {{item.name}}</p>
    <p><b>{{'components.inspection.etape.card.duration'  | translate}}</b> {{item.duration}} minutes</p>
    <p><b>{{'components.inspection.etape.card.description'  | translate}}</b></p>
    <p ng-bind-html="item.description"></p>
    <ion-checkbox ng-disabled="completed" class="item item-input" ng-model="item.done" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" ng-change="itemDone(item)" style="width: 100%; border: 0">{{'components.inspection.etape.card.completed'  | translate}}</ion-checkbox>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JS file (the method is $scope.itemDone)

```
angular.module('app.controllers')
.controller('etapeController', ['$state', '$stateParams', '$scope', '$translate', 'Inspection', 'InspectionItem', 'ItemPhoto', '$ionicHistory', 'Camera', '$ionicPopup', '$q', 'InspectionTree', 'InspectionEtape', 'Loading', 'ExportInspection', 'EtapeComment', 'CommentPhoto',
    function ($state, $stateParams, $scope, $translate, Inspection, InspectionItem, ItemPhoto, $ionicHistory, Camera, $ionicPopup, $q, InspectionTree, InspectionEtape, Loading, ExportInspection, EtapeComment, CommentPhoto) {
        var inspectionId = $stateParams.inspectionId;
        var itemId = $stateParams.itemId;
        $scope.etapes = [];
        Loading.show();

        var loadingPromises = [];
        loadingPromises.push(
            InspectionEtape.getByInspectionId(inspectionId).then(function (f) {
                for (var i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
                    var item = {}
                    item = f[i];
                    $scope.etapes.push(item);
                }
            }));
        loadingPromises.push(
            Inspection.get(inspectionId).then(function (res) {
                $scope.completed = res.status;
            })
        );
        $q.all(loadingPromises).then(function () {
            Loading.hide();
        })


        $scope.itemDetails = function (id) {
            $state.go("app.inspection_etape_comment", { inspectionId: inspectionId, etapeId: id });
        }

        $scope.itemDone = function (etape) {
            if(!$scope.completed)
                InspectionEtape.updateChecked(etape.id, etape.done == true ? 1 : 0);
        }

        $scope.tryFinishInspection = function () {
            $state.go("app.inspection_summary_edit", {inspectionId: inspectionId});
        }
    }]);
```

After spending a lot of time trying to figure out the problem, I decided to turn to the community for help. I would appreciate it very much! Thank you in advance. If you need more clarification, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I ended up finding the solution! Since it didn't work on older devices but it worked on new devices, I thought about installing a webview over the system webview. So all I did was install crosswalk webview (`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`) and it fixed my problem!